# Find MAX DATE - 1 DATE in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of dates in a Google Sheets file that comprises only weekdays. Finding MAX Date from this list is easy, as is finding Max Date - 1 Day.

The issue I need to solve is when Max date is a Monday, which results in no data for Max Date - 1 Day (i.e. a Sunday).

I suspect that if then statements can handle this occurrence, but does a more programatic approach exist using MAX Date? There are solutions for this scenario in Python and SQL, but I found nothing for Google Sheets.

Comment: what formula are you using for your max date cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WORKDAY` and subtract it by 1.

#### Formula:

```
=WORKDAY(MAX(A1:A), -1)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you - had no idea that was available. Works perfectly.